# Как назначить LShift и RShift на две кнопки расположенных на форме?

Tags: c#, winforms

Помогите как назначить <kbd>LShift</kbd> и <kbd>RShift</kbd> на две разные кнопки расположенных на форме (так же <kbd>LAlt</kbd> и <kbd>RAlt</kbd>, <kbd>LCtrl</kbd> и <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>)
Перепробовал все что можно

Вот код:

```
_keyMap = new Dictionary<Keys, Control>();
_keyMap.Add(Keys.A, button1);   //A
_keyMap.Add(Keys.S, button2);   //S
_keyMap.Add(Keys.D, button3);   //D
_keyMap.Add(Keys.F, button6);   //F
_keyMap.Add(Keys.G, button5);   //G
_keyMap.Add(Keys.H, button4);   //H
_keyMap.Add(Keys.J, button9);   //J
_keyMap.Add(Keys.K, button8);   //K
_keyMap.Add(Keys.L, button7);   //L
_keyMap.Add(Keys.Z, button22);  //Z
_keyMap.Add(Keys.X, button21);  //X
_keyMap.Add(Keys.C, button20);  //C
_keyMap.Add(Keys.V, button19);  //V
_keyMap.Add(Keys.B, button18);  //B
_keyMap.Add(Keys.N, button17);  //N
_keyMap.Add(Keys.M, button16);  //M
_keyMap.Add(Keys.LWin, button42);  // LWin
_keyMap.Add(Keys.Q, button32);  //Q
_keyMap.Add(Keys.W, button31);  //W
_keyMap.Add(Keys.E, button30);  //E
_keyMap.Add(Keys.R, button29);  //R
_keyMap.Add(Keys.T, button28);  //T
_keyMap.Add(Keys.Y, button27);  //Y
_keyMap.Add(Keys.U, button26);  //U
_keyMap.Add(Keys.I, button25);  //I
_keyMap.Add(Keys.O, button24);  //O
_keyMap.Add(Keys.P, button23);  //P
_keyMap.Add(Keys.D1, button59);  //1
_keyMap.Add(Keys.D2, button58);  //2
_keyMap.Add(Keys.D3, button57);  //3
_keyMap.Add(Keys.D4, button56);  //4
_keyMap.Add(Keys.D5, button55);  //5
_keyMap.Add(Keys.D6, button54);  //6
_keyMap.Add(Keys.D7, button53);  //7
_keyMap.Add(Keys.D8, button52);  //8
_keyMap.Add(Keys.D9, button51);  //9
_keyMap.Add(Keys.D0, button63);  //0
_keyMap.Add(Keys.OemCloseBrackets,button33);  //}
_keyMap.Add(Keys.OemOpenBrackets, button12);  //{
_keyMap.Add(Keys.OemPeriod, button14);  //>
_keyMap.Add(Keys.Oemtilde, button60);  //Ё
_keyMap.Add(Keys.Oemcomma, button15);  //<
_keyMap.Add(Keys.OemMinus, button62);  //-
_keyMap.Add(Keys.OemPipe, button37);  //|
_keyMap.Add(Keys.Oemplus, button61);  //+
_keyMap.Add(Keys.OemQuotes, button10);  //Ковычки
_keyMap.Add(Keys.OemSemicolon, button11);  //Точка я запятой
_keyMap.Add(Keys.OemQuestion, button13);  // Вопросительный знак Англ ракладка
        
_keyMap.Add(Keys.Space, button44);  //Пробел
_keyMap.Add(Keys.Escape, button77); //ESC
_keyMap.Add(Keys.CapsLock, button35);  //CapsLock
_keyMap.Add(Keys.Tab, button34);  //Tab
        
_keyMap.Add(Keys.F1, button76); //F1
_keyMap.Add(Keys.F2, button75);  //F2
_keyMap.Add(Keys.F3, button74);  //F3
_keyMap.Add(Keys.F4, button73);  //F4
_keyMap.Add(Keys.F5, button72);  //F5
_keyMap.Add(Keys.F6, button71);  //F6
_keyMap.Add(Keys.F7, button70);  //F7
_keyMap.Add(Keys.F8, button69);  //F8
_keyMap.Add(Keys.F9, button68);  //F9
_keyMap.Add(Keys.F10, button67);  //F10
_keyMap.Add(Keys.F11, button66);  //F11
_keyMap.Add(Keys.F12, button65);  //F12
                    
_keyMap.Add(Keys.Back, button64); //BACKSPACE
                    
_keyMap.Add(Keys.Delete, button78); //Delete
        
_keyMap.Add(Keys.Down, button49); //Стрелка Вниз
_keyMap.Add(Keys.Left, button47); //Стрелка Влево
_keyMap.Add(Keys.Up, button50); //Стрелка ВВерх
_keyMap.Add(Keys.Right, button48); //Стрелка Вправо
        
_keyMap.Add(Keys.ShiftKey, button36); // Лeвый Shift
_keyMap.Add(Keys.ControlKey, button40); //Левый CTRL
_keyMap.Add(Keys.Menu, button43); //  Левый Alt
        
_keyMap.Add(Keys.RShiftKey, button39); // Лeвый Shift
_keyMap.Add(Keys.RControlKey, button45); //Левый CTRL
_keyMap.Add(Keys.RMenu, button46); //  Левый Alt
        
_keyMap.Add(Keys.Enter, button38); //Enter
_keyMap.Add(Keys.Snapshot, button79);//Snapshot
        
        
_keyMap.Add(Keys.PageUp, button94); //PageDown
_keyMap.Add(Keys.PageDown, button93); //PageDown
_keyMap.Add(Keys.Divide, button90);  // /
_keyMap.Add(Keys.Multiply, button89); //*
_keyMap.Add(Keys.Add, button100); //+ NumLock
_keyMap.Add(Keys.Subtract, button92); //- NumLock
_keyMap.Add(Keys.None, button92); //- NumLock
_keyMap.Add(Keys.NoName, button92); //- NumLock
        
_keyMap.Add(Keys.End, button95);  // End
_keyMap.Add(Keys.Home, button96);  //Home
_keyMap.Add(Keys.NumLock, button91); //NumLock
_keyMap.Add(Keys.NumPad0, button98); //NumPad0
_keyMap.Add(Keys.NumPad1, button82); //NumPad1
_keyMap.Add(Keys.NumPad2, button81); //NumPad2
_keyMap.Add(Keys.NumPad3, button41); //NumPad3
_keyMap.Add(Keys.NumPad4, button85); //NumPad4
_keyMap.Add(Keys.NumPad5, button84); //NumPad5
_keyMap.Add(Keys.NumPad6, button83); //NumPad6
_keyMap.Add(Keys.NumPad7, button88); //NumPad7
_keyMap.Add(Keys.NumPad8, button87); //NumPad8
_keyMap.Add(Keys.NumPad9, button86); //NumPad9
```

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Control button = _keyMap[e.KeyCode];
        button.BackColor = Color.Green;
        textBox1.Text = " < " + e.KeyCode + " > " + textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Когда я добавил в словарь Lctrl и RCtrl, то мне просто выдавало ошибку

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2569390/12888024 не просто, но возможно

Comment: Ясно спасибо, что уделили время.